# Retrieving data from Biometric Fingerprint Attendance Device

Tags: java, sockets, networking, fingerprint, biometrics

I am trying to connect with a **Biometric Fingerprint Attendance Device** using a Java Program. The device I am using is a **Pegasus T5** Fingerprint scanner. Unfortunately their SDK for this device ([which can be downloaded here](https://code.google.com/p/pegasusequipments/downloads/detail?name=T5%20Time%20Attendance%2020110909OCX.rar&can=2&q=)) covers only C#, .Net, and VB which I have no expertise. And when I have requested the manufacturers, they have replied that there is no **Java SDK** for the device. Even though I have no knowledge on any of those languages, I gave a try to understand the codes in the SDK to find out how the device is connecting and I saw that it is just making a connection with the device using the network ip and port number.

If you refer to the C# SDK of the device, you can see the example I saw on this at 
*frmEvent.cs* which in the `cmdStartMoniter_Click` method, make the connection as follows.

```
bRet = bpc.StartEventCapture(0, util.pubIPAddrToLong(txtSourceIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNumber.Text));
```

And that refers to the method `StartEventCapture` as `public virtual bool StartEventCapture(int dwCommType, int dwParam1, int dwParam2);` which is in a *.dll* file as it appears and which I have lost my track as I have further knowledge on how to figure out the code.

However keeping that example I had seen in my head, as my next step I started researching for a global standard on how to connect, send and retrieve data with a Fingerprint Device which again I wasn't lucky enough to find a clear solution. But with some examples from some people who have been trying to deal with the same and the example I saw by myself, I tried to connect with the device by creating a `Socket` object but when I executed it, it only resulted with the `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

There are four questions

1. Is there any Java SDK for Biometric Fingerprint Attendance Devices which I can use for my device as well?
2. Is there any general, standard way to connect, send and retrieve data from such device using Java?
3. **If** connecting to the device via a `Socket` is a solution, is there any specific, standard requests I should be sending to the device in order to receive a response from it?
4. If the attempt I have made is a way to do it, what I have I done wrong with it and how should I correct the problem?

This is the code I used to connect with the device.

```
    String host = "192.168.168.100";
    int port = Integer.parseInt("5005");

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while (true){
            line = in.readLine();
            if (line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Try to use `netstat -an` to see if this device is even listening for traffic on the port you trying to connect to.

Comment: That is a good idea. I will try that. Although I'm pretty sure that it communicates via that port because it is the port which the manufacturer provided client software uses to communicate with the device. And when I check on the interned it seemed that the `5005` is a default standard port number for fingerprint devices. But I wonder if I should send any particular request in order to get a response or the device transmits data upon each scan. However I will try `netstat` commands like you suggested and see if it is listening on that port. Thank you @nrathaus!

Comment: So use `wireshark` to sniff traffic being sent to that port, it could be for example that the traffic is SSL encrypted, which would make what you want to do a bit tricky

Comment: I did find other products that work on port 5005 and are fingerprinting devices, so maybe there is some sort of known protocol, however I cannot locate one

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990924/handling-a-biometric-fingerprint-attendance-device-by-using-socket-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Each biomatric device have normally lAN port or Web interface. Biomatric device sends data on specific port. for example

```
192.168.1.23:8080
```

you can make connection to it using java sockets and can read data ..

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.23","8080");
```

keep it up

enjoy

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access the biometric machines to associate with your web application, then look for CAMSUnit machines. CAMS provides the [WEB APIs](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=Quora&ts=25/02/2017&ornr=%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732928/retrieving-data-from-biometric-fingerprint-attendance-device%22&tpc=Stackoverflow&it=CAMS-API&learnref=http://camsunit.com/#api) for their biometric machines. It supports registering the callback URL which gets called every time a new attendance is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Just gone through the sample code downloaded from the link shared in the question. let me share my few cents, if that helps you.

As per the code, we can not directly connect the machine through simple socket programming. Which is possible, only if you know the low level communication protocol which none of the manufactures do share. So, you must follow their SDKs only.

Coming to the SDK

> AxSBXPC::StartEventCapture has three paramters, where 1st one says TCP/IP or serial communication. 0 means TCP/IP, and 1 means serial communication.
>
> for TCP/IP, 2nd and 3rd parameters are IP and PORT.
>
> First implement a simple program by just connecting the machine through TCP/IP. Once success, you can move implementing the events and handling the data. Before running the program, you must check if the biometric machine is pingable in the computer by the configured IP.

You need to find events for attendance, user update, and etc., and implement them as per the need. Events are triggered with XML parameter which holds all the data Data, so you must find the keys of every item you like to read.

Pegasus doesn't provide the direct cloud communication, if you need the direct cloud communication, as Victor pointed out, you will have to use the web api supported biometric machines.